# What Controls the Mapping of the Rails Controller Method to the View Rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application which is not routing as I expected. The search method in the controller is rending show. I've cut down the code to the minimal components and I am posting them here as suggested.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :backups
  get 'backups/search' => 'backups#search'
  resources :components
  resources :backup_media
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :backups
  has_many :backup_media, :through => :backups
end

class BackupMedium < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :backups
  has_many :components, :through => :backups
end

class Backup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :component
  belongs_to :backup_medium

  # value to match either the name of the component or backup_medium
  def self.search(value)
    tables = "backups, components, backup_media"
    joins = "backups.backup_medium_id = backup_media.id and components.id = backups.component_id"
    c = find_by_sql "select * from #{tables} where components.name like '%#{value}%' and #{joins}"
    b = find_by_sql "select * from #{tables} where backup_media.name like '%#{value}%' and #{joins}"
    c.count > 0 ? c : b
  end  
end

class BackupsController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @backups = Backup.search(params[:search])
    render 'index'
  end
  def index
    @backups = Backup.all
  end
  def show
    # this would normally be the code to show an individual backup
    # but I'm re-using the code from index because the routing is broken
    @backups = Backup.all
  end
end
```

views/backups/_search.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag backups_search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= label_tag(:search, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], {:placeholder => 'Component or Media'  }%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

views/backups/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing Backups</h1>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= render :partial => 'search' %>

<table>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>component_id</th>
      <th>backup_medium_id</th>
    </tr>

    <% @backups.each do |backup| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= backup.id %></td>
        <td><%= backup.component.name %></td>
        <td><%= backup.backup_medium.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

views/backups/show.html.erb is copied from index.html.erb since it is incorrectly receiving the search results

```
<h1>Show Backup</h1>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= render :partial => 'search' %>

<table>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>component_id</th>
      <th>backup_medium_id</th>
    </tr>

    <% @backups.each do |backup| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= backup.id %></td>
        <td><%= backup.component.name %></td>
        <td><%= backup.backup_medium.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Suggestions on improving the search method will be welcomed.

As mentioned above, after the search is executed, the show.html.erb is rendered instead of search.html.erb

For a working demo (with better code thanks to suggestions here) see
https://github.com/pamh09/rails-search-demo

Comment: Post the form and the full log

Comment: This could plausibly be an error in your view, or your controller, or your routes file. It's really hard to debug a verbal description of your code :)  Can you please edit your question, and show us the relevant snippet for each of these files so we can determine which it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In debugging I found that rails consistently routed to the wrong view when it was unhappy with the return object coming from the model.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a `backups_search_path` in your routes, therefore it is treating `search` in the query string as an `id` and thus rendering show.html.erb, so try

```
get 'backups/search' => 'backups#search', as: :backups_search
```

Comment: Timmy,  I think this is a good thing to check.  I do have " get 'backups/search' => 'backups#search'" in routes.rb but for other people looking for help with routing, this is a good thing to check.